# Creating multiple PDF combined into one file from excel

Tags: excel, pdf

I am currently using the below to create individual pdf files (each time a new value is put into C4, a new pdf with different data is generated). Is there a way that all of these pdf can be saved into one file?

Thank you in advance for your help

Q

```
Sub moveselection()
Dim i As Integer


For i = 1 To 108


Range("C4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Offset(i, 0).Value
ThisFile = Range("C4").Value


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:="T:\Maths\QM" & _
ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value & ".pdf", _
From:=1, _
To:=1, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False


Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Excel might generate PDFs, but I don't believe that it is actually a tool for manipulating PDFs, so it is unlikely to provide you with  PDF document merging functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than saving as pdf each time why not Create a new workbook before you enter the loop and then copy the active sheet to this new workbook then after the loop ends you can export the entire workbook to pdf?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, sorry. How do I get all the information into a new worksheet?